# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2 Error converting data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can you help me to do this view correctly?

code:

```
SELECT CustomerName, C_CUR, SUM(BILL_AMT) AS B_AMT, C_CODE
FROM     dbo.BILLS
WHERE  (BILL_TYPE = 2)
GROUP BY C_CODE, C_CUR, CustomerName
      UNION ALL
SELECT C_CODE, SUM(BILL_AMT) AS RT_AMT, C_CUR, CustomerName
FROM     dbo.RTN_BILLS
WHERE  (BILL_TYPE = 2)
GROUP BY C_CODE, C_CUR, CustomerName
```

error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Comment: The columns are clearly not in the same order in both branches of the UNION

Comment: To expand on @MartinSmith 's comment, `UNION (ALL`) doesn't union the data based on the *names/aliases* of the columns, it bases it on the *oridinal* position of them. `SELECT 1 AS one, 2 AS two UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS two, 1 AS one` would result in `1` and `2` being in the column `one`. Aliasing in the 2nd dataset and latter are effectively ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the columns for both parts of the `UNION` in the same order.